# In Cocoa, using webview, How to display a link in a status bar when mouse is over?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, mouseover

As title says, I'm using webview to display a site and I need to show the link in a status bar when the mouse is over an hypertext...
How can I do this? I'm sure it is something very easy but till now I could not find anything about this...
Thanks for any help,
Massy

Comment: Actually, it is not as easy as you think. Even Safari doesn't do this by default. An extension is needed. I am not sure how you would do this?

Comment: I can't believe there's not a methode to get a link... in Safari if you click on Show status bar it appears.... I'm pretty sure there must be a simple way to do it... thing is I still have to find it... :)

Comment: Oh, glad you found it. That is interesting. I did not know Safari had a way to sure the link. Learn something new every day. Glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it! I was sooo sure it was sooo easy...
Here's what I did for anyone who will have my same problem:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender mouseDidMoveOverElement:(NSDictionary *)elementInformation modifierFlags:(unsigned int)modifierFlags
{    
   NSArray* keys = [elementInformation objectForKey:WebElementLinkURLKey];

   //here I pass the link to a label
   if (keys != nil) [statusBarLabel setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",keys]];
   else [statusBarLabel setStringValue:@""];

//  NSLog(@"%@",keys);
}
```

Also don't forget to UIDelegate your webView.
Peace, Massy